# In Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin load csv file(text file)?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am using the following script in gremlin to create a graph by using CSV file (text file):

code:

*g = TinkerGraph.open()*

*vs=[ ] as Set*

*new File("edges.txt").eachLine{l->p=l.split("\t");vs<<p[0];vs<<p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYyf2.png);}*

*vs.each{v->g.addVertex(v)}*

*new File("edges.txt").eachLine{l->p=l.split("\t");g.addEdge(g.getVertex(p[0]),g.getVertex(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYyf2.png)),"friend")}*

*g.E*

---

When the above code is applied these errors occur:

*No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph.getVertex() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYyf2.png)*

*Possible solutions: addVertex([Ljava.lang.Object;), getAt(java.lang.String)*

---

**Note that csv file("edges.txt") is like this**:

*Source  Destination*

2        4

3        5

2        8
[image: This a ("edges.txt") file:]

Comment: I'm curious why you are using the Graph API (addVertex, addEdge) and not the Traversal API (addV,addE), but regardless, without a sample of the CSV file it's hard to provide a tested answer. Can you add a few rows from "edges.txt" to the question? Also are you running this from the Gremlin console or just as a Groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to use the Traversal API, as there is no `addEdge` method exported by TinkerGraph (`addEdge` is actually a method of the `Vertex` class). In general using the Traversal API is the way to go for application code. The Graph API is more for backend developers these days (database providers).

```java
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()

vs=[ ] as Set

new File(edges.txt").eachLine{l->p=l.split(",");vs<<p[0];vs<<p1;}

vs.each{v->g.addV().property(T.id,v).next()}

new File("edges.txt").eachLine{l->p=l.split(",");g.addE("friend").from(V(p[0])).to(V(p[1])).next()}
```

I ran this in the gremlin console and after all the steps above have been run, we can see the graph has been created. Note I changed the separator to be a comma, just as it was easier to type when I was creating the test file.

```java
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[0][2-friend->4]
==>e[1][3-friend->5]
==>e[2][2-friend->8]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mr Kelvin Lawrence
I am executing it successfully according to the code you sent me.

Comment: Great to hear - I would be grateful if you can accept the answer given it worked for you so others can see that the question is resolved.